# HTML/CSS - auto size the width of content in a wrapper

Tags: html, css

I have a content div with a variable length of content, horizontally.
I would like the width of this content div to auto-size depending on the length of it's content. For example, I would like to be able to remove the arbitrary "20%" value, and have the div size accordingly. Currently removing the 20% value from the width is forcing it to resize to 100% of it's container. What CSS am I missing?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gbm09erp/)

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <span>One</span>
    <span>Two</span>
    <span>Three</span>
    <span>Four</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `text-align:center` on the wrapper and set the display of the content div to inline or inline-block:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid green;
  text-align:center;
}
.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <span>One</span>
    <span>Two</span>
    <span>Three</span>
    <span>Four</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bear in mind when resizing smaller borders will collapse

Comment: @Syden if the content div is inline-block then the behavior is the same as flexbox.

Comment: Edited answer with comparison, also you can resize the fiddle window yourself on an external one. Flexbox is very versatile for resizing purposes. Regards.

Comment: @Syden I said inline-block, not inline behaves exactly like flexbox. You're making an incorrect comparison.

Answer (score 2):

If you want fluid resizing behavior I'd suggest flexbox:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  /*width: 20%;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <span>One</span>
    <span>Two</span>
    <span>Three</span>
    <span>Four</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

inline:

[image]

flexbox:

[image]